# How to convert unsigned char* to Python list using Swig?

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

I have a C++ class method like this:

```
class BinaryData
{
public:
    ...
    void serialize(unsigned char* buf) const;
};
```

`serialize` function just get binary data as `unsigned char*`.
I use SWIG to wrap this class.
I want to read binary data as `byte array` or `int array` in python.

Python Code:

```
buf = [1] * 1000;
binData.serialize(buf);
```

But it occurs exception that can't convert to `unsigned char*`.
How can I call this function in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing to do is to convert it inside Python:

```
buf = [1] * 1000;
binData.serialize(''.join(buf));
```

Will work out of the box, but is potentially inelegant depending on what Python users are expecting. You can workaround that using SWIG either [inside Python code](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn42), e.g. with:

```
%feature("shadow") BinaryData::serialize(unsigned char *) %{
def serialize(*args):
    #do something before
    args = (args[0], ''.join(args[1]))
    $action
    #do something after
%}
```

Or inside the generated interface code, e.g. using [buffers protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#buffer-related-functions):

```
%typemap(in) unsigned char *buf %{
    //    use PyObject_CheckBuffer and
    //    PyObject_GetBuffer to work with the underlying buffer
    // AND/OR
    //    use PyIter_Check and
    //    PyObject_GetIter
%}
```

Where you prefer to do this is a personal choice based on your preferred programming language and other situation specific constraints.